# Enable clang for project

Tags: c++, build, cmake, clang

I decided to test clang in my project. There is CMake build system so, I run such command:

```
cmake ../  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++

MAKE_C_COMPILER= clang
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= clang++

-- The C compiler identification is Clang
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ -- works
```

But building has been failed:

Here is first line of `make VERBOSE=1`

```
clang++   -DApplicationManager_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/ClanLib-2.2 -I/usr/include/Box2D   -Wall -g -msse2 -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/ApplicationManager.cpp.o -c ApplicationManager.cpp
```

And list of errors http://pastebin.com/MQmhbW4D.

Here is also screenshot of console: http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5347/clang.png

Comment: As I know, LLVM is still have some issuses with c++, so don't expect any thing from it with c++ code, http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang has not implemented `__is_trivial`, so it seems like you're out of luck for now.

[Link to bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9472)

Answer (score 1):

The clang project recommends using libstdc++ from GCC 4.5 or earlier.  See the [Clang C++ Status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) page if you're interested in using C++'0x with the GCC 4.4 libstdc++.

-Chris